# How do I prevent NuGet restore from downloading a Chocolatey package?

Tags: nuget, chocolatey

I have a vs2015 solution that relies on NuGet packages. On my dev box, VS2015 takes care of restoring packages. On my CI server, I use the command line "NuGet.exe restore" before calling MSBuild.

This all works fine, except... on a new CI server, the "Nuget.exe restore" command downloads an nunit package that has a tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1 instead of libs\nunit.framework.dll. This breaks my build, as nunit.framework.dll is not found.

1) Why is this happening?
2) What should I do about it?

What I've tried so far...

- install chocolately - no change
- try "NuGet.exe restore" in my development environment - also produces the chocolatey package instead of the NuGet package.
- v2 and v3 of NuGet.exe on my dev machine - same result

Comment: Is it possible you can show the packages.config that you are using?  Also, have you set up any additional sources for nuget?  Can you show also the nuget command you are using to do the restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure that NuGet doesn't contain Chocolatey as a source. You may have a hold over from a time when they were closely tied to each other. Or you may be running into NuGet search paths finding a nuget.config that points to Chocolatey as a source, possibly in your solution.

Comment: It was a source issue - not so much from Chocolatey, but from another pkg source that decided offering NuGet would be helpful :). Many thanks, your suggestion and a quick WireShark session showed the source of my issue.